# prevent nuget package modifications

Tags: nuget

Sometimes, packages like to modify my web.config, add references I don't really need, or implement stuff like `WebActivator` and hook my `Application_Start` (where I actually handle that somehow else, like using an IoC container.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NuGet Package Manager doesn't really support this scenario but one way to do would be to use nuget.exe instead.

Package installation through nuget.exe simply extracts files to a location. It doesn't modify the project files or references. The downside is that you'll have to manually add references, content and other config changes that are normally required.